# Is there a Lambda trigger that will push/copy files from S3 bucket to the SFTP server?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda

I am looking for a way to set up a Lambda trigger, where if any files are uploaded into the S3 bucket, the trigger will push/copy the file(s) to the SFTP server.

Comment: This is too broad. Take a read of this https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/NotificationHowTo.html , choose a path and get back to us if you run into problems.

Comment: What do you mean by "trigger the API to download the file"? Download to where? Where does this code/API run? Lambda, EC2, your own computer?

Comment: My goal is whenever a file is uploaded to the S3 bucket, I want to create a lambda trigger where it would push/copy the file to the SFTP server.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use the following algorithm:

- Log in to AWS console,
- Lambda service,
- Create a new lambda function (choose a proper runtime);

Then you have to set a trigger (a left pane). If you want to trigger your lambda by s3 bucket then click on s3.

Then you have to configure your trigger (choose your bucket and trigger action). 
After you complete all of this steps it's a time to write a handler file.

Do not forget that every single trigger has to be in the same region as lambda.

Comment: When creating the trigger, what role should I use? I want the trigger to push/copy the file that got uploaded to the SFTP server. Is this possible?

Comment: I mean sure, but it's nothing have to do with IAM. You just need to grant access to lambda (read/write to s3 and same for s3). Then in your handler file, you have to code what you need to be done. If you can't figure out I can take a look later.

Comment: I have tried to code this and I couldn't figure it out. Please let me know if I could get any help! Thank you so much for your time! @AironBrynchke